# $http.get method is not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a method in my Web API controller returning a boolean:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public bool ValidateEmployee(string id)
 {
     return myRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(id);
 }
```

and here is my UI that is calling that Web API via Angular;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Employee ID/PIN</title>
<script src="../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="EmployeeLoginCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myClassesApp">
<div ng-controller="myClassesController">
    <form ng-submit="ValidateEmployeeId()" method="get" id="frmLogin" action="">
        <input ng-model="empId" type="text" id="txtEmpId" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
        <br />
        <span id="lblMsg">{{EmployeeValidate}}</span>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my angular controller:

```
(function () {
    angular.module("myClassesApp", []).controller("myClassesController", EmpCtrlFunction);
    EmpCtrlFunction.$inject("$scope", "$http");
    function EmpCtrlFunction($scope, $http) {
        $scope.ValidateEmployeeId = function () {
            alert($scope.empId);
            $http.get('http://localhost:49358/api/myClasses/ValidateEmployee/' + $scope.empId).
                   then(function (result) {
                       alert(result);
                      $scope.EmployeeValidate = result.data;
             });
        }

    };
})();
```

When I enter an id and click a button, the line alert($scope.empId); gets executed and then it never gets to $http.get

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you check your network tab in inspector, is there any requests?

Answer (score 0):

dont use alert since alert is blocking and causes all kinds of problems in angular, use console.log instead to dump variable values and use the console tab in your browser to view output

```
console.log($scope.empId);
```

use the NET tab in your browser to view what HTTP requests are being made

Comment: In network tabl I see this: Name    Status  Type
EmployeeLogin.html 304  Other
angular.js  304  EmplyeeLogin.html:5
EmployeeLoginCtrl.js 304  EmplyeeLogin.html:6

Comment: That shows requests from the HTML files, you want a request for /ValidateEmployee - clear the console and then refresh the page - what do you get? what is the console.log statement saying?

Comment: There isn't anything in my console window. I hit Fn+F5 to refresh the request but the same thing happens

Comment: 304 means the file is cached - clear your borwser cache and refresh - did you put a console.log statement just before the $http request?

Comment: I cleared the cache and re-ran it and gotten the same thing in Network tab, except now the status is 200

Answer (score 0):

The way you inject dependencies is wrong. it should be

```
EmpCtrlFunction.$inject = ["$scope", "$http"];
```

as $inject is not a function.

Comment: I changed it but did not make any difference